# Add rows to StringGrid with variables as cell data?

Tags: lazarus, delphi

I have a form with two TEdit components. On another form, I would like a row to be added to the TStringGrid with the data from the two TEdits. How do I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
procedure TSecondForm.StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  string1 := Edit1.Text;
  string2 := Edit2.Text;

  MainForm.StringGrid1.RowCount := MainForm.StringGrid1.RowCount + 1; // this adds the rows, but I don't know how to make it so that the two variables are inputed into two seperate cells
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Remy. To clarify, I'm aware of the Cells property, but I'm just struggling with the logic of implementing Cells with all my variables.

Comment: You might do best to google yourself a TStringGrid tutorial - there are plenty around.  E.g. http://sheepdogguides.com/dt2k.htm  There are plenty on youtube too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Delphi and FreePascal/Lazarus, you can use the [`TStringGrid.Cells`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid.Cells) property after incrementing the `RowCount`, eg:

```
procedure TSecondForm.StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  string1, string2: string;
  row: integer;
begin
  string1 := Edit1.Text;
  string2 := Edit2.Text;

  row := MainForm.StringGrid1.RowCount;
  MainForm.StringGrid1.RowCount := row + 1;
  MainForm.StringGrid1.Cells[0, row] := string1;
  MainForm.StringGrid1.Cells[1, row] := string2;
end;
```

In FreePascal/Lazarus only, you can alternately use the `TStringGrid.InsertRowWithValues()` method instead:

```
procedure TSecondForm.StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  string1, string2: string;
begin
  string1 := Edit1.Text;
  string2 := Edit2.Text;

  MainForm.StringGrid1.InsertRowWithValues(MainForm.StringGrid1.RowCount, [string1, string2]);
end;
```

Comment: Awesome, seems so simple now.